# Geektool: cat command doesn't work

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-snow-leopard, geektool

I'm trying to get Geektool to display a txt file, but the Geeklet stays blank.

It displays just fine when I enter:

> date
>   date +%d

But when I enter the following it does not display:

> cat ~/Desktop/todo.txt

I've copy pasted the text into terminal and it returns the text just fine.

I'm using v3.0.1 and OSX 10.6.8

Comment: I created a file with some text and tried, works fine. I'm running Geektool 3.3.1 on OSX 10.11.6. Is there any reason you're running ancient software? :)

You could try using the File/Log Geeklet instead.

Comment: I can't upgrade beyond Snow Leopard, and the newest Geektool doesn't work, that's why :)  How would one use the File or Log Geeklet to display the text of a txt file?